# SQLite DataAdapter UpdateBatchSize Error

Tags: c#, sqlite, dataadapter

Background:

I am attempting to copy a DataTable to a SQLite database. In comparison to an equivalent data set running on a SQLServer database, the SQLite version takes about 5 times longer. In order to streamline this, I am trying to use the UpdateBatchSize property of the SQLiteDataAdapter I'm using to enable batch processing.

Problem:

However, any attempt to set the value results in a System.NotSupportedException. How do you properly set that value? See code:

```
public int InsertDataTable(DataTable dt, string selectCommand)
{
    SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, m_conn);
    myAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;
    int rowsAffected = myAdapter.Update(dt.Select());
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: Also: since this is my first question, any critiques/recommendations on the formatting/asking would be appreciated.

Comment: is the connection m_conn initiated anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, it's initialized earlier. The init line is: using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}", file)))

Is there a trigger I need to set in that init line?

Comment: instead of 0 can you try manually setting the UpdateBatchSize > 1, i.e. 10 and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately that results in the same error.

Comment: just to be sure, what .Net framework version are you using

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 3.5 because when I tried to use 4.0 I got errors. Is that a possible reason?

Comment: I don't think so, UpdateBatchSize property should be available since 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same performance increase can be accomplished through another method. Instead of trying to modify the UpdateBatchSize, create a SQLiteTransaction that encompasses the update.

```
public int InsertDataTable(DataTable dt, string selectCommand)
    {
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, m_conn);
        SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
        SQLiteTransaction transaction = m_conn.BeginTransaction();
        builder.GetInsertCommand().Transaction = transaction;
        int rowsAffected = adapter.Update(dt.Select());
        transaction.Commit();            
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Source:

[SQLiteTransction](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.html)

Comment: If anyone has information on why the other method didn't work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't perform sqlite operations inside a transaction then one is implicitly created per sql statement. This makes it take a lot longer, I guess it has to do various file locking things for each statement. Hence you should always explicitly create transactions when working with SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

The point of UpdateBatchSize is to group together SQL statements before they're sent down the wire to the database server. In SQLite you don't need to do this since there's no network connection: you're using direct file access. That's probably why you get an error, presumably the driver realises it doesn't do anything with that setting so it errors.

If you're using SQL Server then increasing that setting to 2 means that it will group two UPDATE statements together and send them, rather than sending them one at a time. Setting it to a larger number means fewer roundtrips to the server. So if you were using SQL Server you'd set it to a larger number to reduce the impact of network latency. Setting it to 0 means no limit to the number of statements per batch, but that could mean your batches are stupidly big.

The reason creating an explicit transaction solved your performance issues is that if you don't perform sqlite operations inside a transaction then one is implicitly created per sql statement. This makes it take a lot longer, presumably it has to do file locking and journalling and various things for each statement. Hence you should always explicitly create transactions when working with SQLite and this will give you an order of magnitude improvement over not doing so.